# Ruby dynamic Regex condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like make a regex on controller (RoR). i have tried this code :

```
  @widget_check = ClanTemplatesWidget.find(params[:id])
  unless params[:config].blank?
    #@widget_check.config in database value = [{"input":"string","name":"code", "label":"Code clan","validation":"^([#][A-Z0-9]{7})$"}]
    JSON.parse(@widget_check.config).each do |config,i|
     regexp = Regexp.new(config["validation"])
     if regexp.match(params[:config][config["name"]])
       @error = 0
     else
       @error = 1
     end
    end
    @widget.config = params[:config].to_json
  end
```

For information my data is on the database. If i inspect the two params i have that :

**config["validation"] =** /^([#][A-Z0-9]{8})$/

**params[:config][config["name"]] =** #2YL9GR9R

If i rewrite my code with the data it's work fine (like that) :

```
if /^([#][A-Z0-9]{8})$/.match("#2YL9GR9R")
  @error = 0
else
  @error = 1
end
```

Comment: Since `#2YL9GR9R` doesn't have quotes, I would guess that both values (`params[:config][config["name"]]` and `config["validation"]`) are in fact strings.

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you have?

Comment: How do you set `config["validation"]`?

Comment: In database it's a json form input.

Comment: You are saving your config values in a database, right? But how / where do you set the `config` variable / hash? You have to somehow retrieve the values from the database and assign them to `config`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `config["validation"]` contains a string that looks like a regexp, but it is not. But you can build a regexp out of a string:

```
regexp = Regexp.new(config["validation"])
regexp.match(params[:config][config["name"]])
```

Since `Regexp.new` expects a string without the surrounding `/.../`, you just might want to omit them.

Comment: Or you could use `params[:config][config["name"]].match(config["validation"]`) – [`String#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-match) implicitly converts the argument to a `Regexp`. (the surrounding `/.../` must be removed in either case)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i've tried your code but still not working.

Comment: @Shinix did you remove the leading and trailing `/`? You have to store `"^([#][A-Z0-9]{7})$"` instead of `"/^([#][A-Z0-9]{7})$/"`

Comment: Yes, i've tried without `/` (i've update the code on my first post). If i use config data it's not working but if i use text like that it's work :/   `regexp = Regexp.new("/^([#][A-Z0-9]{8})$/")` `regexp.match("#2YL9GR9R")`

Comment: @Shinix double check (within your code) if `config["validation"] == "^([#][A-Z0-9]{8})$"` and if `params[:config][config["name"]] == "#2YL9GR9R"`. If they don't match, print both values via `p value` or `puts value.inspect`. Maybe there's a trailing newline or another minor difference.

Comment: @Shinix BTW, your updated code does not include the `Regexp.new` part, not sure if this is intentional.

Comment: Yes, i think use `.match()` or `Regexp.new` is the same because i've the  same result ^^. Now i've updated my first post with `Regexp.new`

Comment: @Shinix it's not the same. Calling `match` on a string invokes [`String#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-match), whereas calling it on a regex invokes [`Regexp#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match). However, what about my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992225/ruby-dynamic-regex-condition/39992342#comment67267303_39992342) – have you checked your values?

Comment: Uh, i'm sorry i've not see your previous comment. I've checked now with `inspect` the two values and i've that :

Comment: `puts config["validation"].inspect` show `"^([#][A-Z0-9]{7})$"` and `puts params[:config][config["name"]].inspect` show `"#2YL9GR9R" `

Comment: Oh ! no ! i'v in the regex "{7}" but it's {8} for working fine... Thanks ! your regexp.match work fine now !

Comment: @Shinix `config["validation"] == "^([#][A-Z0-9]{8})$"` would have revealed the typo. Don't trust your eyes when comparing strings ;-)